# Node with mongodb wrong date in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In mongodb i have date like this

```
ISODate("2020-08-03T00:00:00.000+05:30"),
```

After querying the date looks like this

```
2020-08-02T18:30:00.000Z
```

I want correct date 2020-08-03 what i am doing wrong in this?

Comment: The date is getting converted into ISO format, Indian Standard Time is 5.30 hours ahead of ISO time hence date is getting shifted back.

Comment: How can i get correct date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response guys i found solution to convert iso date to local datetime

```
//If you want to parse in node
   var date = new Date("2020-08-02T18:30:00.000Z").toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
    });

 console.log(date) //'8/3/2020, 12:00:00 AM'
```

I'm using flutter so i have used

```
//If you want to parse in Flutter
DateTime date = DateTime.parse("2020-08-02T18:30:00.000Z").toUtc();
DateTime dateLocal = date.toLocal();

print(dateLocal) //2020-08-03 00:00:00.000
```